# Is it possible to run iOS simulator on AWS EC2 Mac instance?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2, simulator

I need to run an iOS App on different regions of the world to test how a streaming service perfoms from different points of the planet.

For that I noticed AWS provides EC2 Mac instances in some regions.
The price of this Mac instances is quite expensive, so I would like to know first if it is possible to run an iOS App on an iOS simulator inside these EC2 instances.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you planning on getting touch input on those running simulators or extracting any output of those running systems? Shouldn't the streaming performance be independent of the OS anyway?

Comment: @luk2302 this app was specfically designed to test the perfomance of our streaming service on AVPlayer on iOS 14 from different parts of the world. While the streaming is playing we collect a lot of information like latency for example and send it to our servers every second.  So we would like to know if the stream comes from New York, how much latency we could get (at the same network bandwidth) playing the stream in Singapore or Dublin for example.

Comment: I understand that, but the throughput and latency should not change between running a shell script and an iOS application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I didn't find any answer about if it possible to run an iOS simulator on a EC2 Mac instance on AWS I tested it myself.

**YES**, it is possible.
You can download Xcode and get the simulators as usual.

[image]